# Gamma function a generalized fictorial function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I learned all the properties of gamma function. I did some of questions about gamma function. I know gamma function is generalized fictorial function that always positive. And i know that Gamma of 1/2 equals sqaure root pi. But i stuck on how to evaluate gamma 4/3. Please some one help me on this.
Besides gamma function i knew about beta function which is also calles Euler beta function. I know the relation between Beta and Gamma funtion , Legendre's Dupocation formula and other topics related to Gamma and Beta function.

Comment: I don't think there's a nice formula for $\Gamma(4/3)$.

Comment: So you are saying we cant compute such values of gamma function. If we can then what is the formula???

Answer (score 1):

You can use

$$
\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right) = \Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{3}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)
$$

And that's pretty much it. $\Gamma(1/3)$ is a trascendental number, doesn't have a nice representation such as $\Gamma(1/2)$.

As for your statements, some of them are not true, e.g., $\Gamma(x)$ is not always positive, here's an [example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma(-1%2F2))

$$
\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) = -2\sqrt{\pi} < 0
$$

Comment: Can you expalain next step . . Or gave me hint to solve further ... #caverac

Comment: @NaeemIvy Which step?

Comment: Actually i knew how to split Gamma 4/3 into 1/3 Gamma (1/3) . But i couldn't solve gamma 1/3 . . Plz help me on this. And kindly can you tell me about transdental number.

Comment: @NaeemIvy Showing that $\Gamma(1/3)$ is transcendental is not trivial at all. I know [this](https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/2705614079/ref=nosim/ericstreasuretro) book has a proof